# connecting angularJS to plotly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plotly

So I want to use angularJS to get data from a server and plot the data using Plotly. I am running a server in the background. The HTML I am using is shown below. I think it is pretty straight forward.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testign Plotly</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='plotly.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='angular.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='plotApp.js'></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='myApp'>
<div id="graph" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" ng-controller='plotXY'>

    // var data = [{
    //     x:[1,2,3,4],
    //     y:[5,3,6,12],
    // }];

    Plotly.plot( $('#graph')[0], {{data}}  , {margin: {t:0}});
</script>
<hr><div ng-controller='plotXY'>{{data}}</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have the angularJS script `plotApp.js` as shown below, also very simple ...

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('plotXY', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.refresh = function(){
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/data').success(function(data){
            $scope.data = {};
            for(k in data){$scope.data[k] = data[k].map(Number);}
            $scope.data = [$scope.data];
        });
    };

    $scope.refresh();
});
```

Now, The compiled HTML for this (saved from the browser) is shown below ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-shim{visibility:hidden;}.ng-anchor{position:absolute;}</style>
    <title>Testign Plotly</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Testign%20Plotly_files/plotly.js"></script><style></style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Testign%20Plotly_files/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Testign%20Plotly_files/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Testign%20Plotly_files/plotApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="ng-scope" ng-app="myApp">
<div id="graph" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
<script class="ng-scope" type="text/javascript" ng-controller="plotXY">

    // var data = [{
    //     x:[1,2,3,4],
    //     y:[5,3,6,12],
    // }];

    Plotly.plot( $('#graph')[0], {{data}}  , {margin: {t:0}});
</script>
<hr><div class="ng-scope ng-binding" ng-controller="plotXY">[{"y":[1.26642e-14,2.8044e-14,6.1484e-14,1.33457e-13],"x":[-10,-9,-8,-7]}]</div>
</body></html>
```

As you can tell, the portion within the `div` gets updates with the right data. However, that within the script doesn't!

Just so you know, If I use the `data` variable (the one that is commented out), I am able to see the plot. So Plotly is working.

I want the client to pull data from the server and have plotly display it. I can do it if I create the entire page from the server and send it over. However, I think that this way is much better. However, for some reason, I dont seem to be able to connect the data source in Plotly, to that in angularJS. I would really appreciate some help ...

Answer (score 0):

The Plotly-method of updating the data seems to be through [Plotly.restyle()](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotly-restyle):

```
var update = {x: [[0,1,2], y: [[5,2,4]]};
Plotly.restyle(graphDiv, update, 0);
```

Just make sure that you use double arrays when you want to update an array. Plotly supports updating multiple traces at once via arrays, so `[[0,1,2],[1,3,4]]` would update two traces

Comment: It turns out that you have to use a `directive`. Here is a small tutorial I wrote after a lot of help from folks here http://codepen.io/omolluska/post/rapid-prototyping-of-systems-for-visual-display-iii

Comment: Interesting. I think I would still use the `Plotly.restyle()` instead of `newPlot()` to only update traces, not redraw the whole graph.